# Gulp not compiling ALL sass files

Tags: sass, gulp

**Gulp Function:**

```
function style() {
//1.where is my scss
return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss') //gets all files ending with .scss in src/scss
//2. pass that file through sass compiler
.pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
//3. where do I save the compiled css file
.pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
//4. stream change to all browsers
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**Expected output:**
`syles.css` will have styles written in `syles.scss` and `vendor.scss`

**Actual Output:**
`syles.css` will have styles written in `syles.scss` alone. `vendor.scss` styles are not added in `styles.css`

Answer (score 0):

Your actual output is correct.  You need to `@use` a partial into your `styles.scss` if you want only one file `styles.css` output containing the `vendor.scss` content.

> **Modules**
>
> You don't have to write all your Sass in a single file. You can split
>   it up however you want with the @use rule. This rule loads another
>   Sass file as a module, which means you can refer to its variables,
>   mixins, and functions in your Sass file with a namespace based on the
>   filename. Using a file will also include the CSS it generates in your
>   compiled output!

from https://sass-lang.com/guide

so in your `styles.scss` at the top:

`@use 'vendor`;

and then rename `vendor.scss` to `_vendor.scss`